# I'm getting error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined' in console while creating WEB NOTIFICATIONS USING LARAVEL AND PUSHER CHANNELS

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I'm trying to send a notification for web using https://pusher.com 
I've implement  each and everything given in pusher documentation but now still im getting error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined" in console

please review if there is any issue in my code
I have created FormSubmitted event inside App\Events
it looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class FormSubmitted implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $text;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($text)
    {
        //
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'form-submitted';
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

I've created counter.blade.php inside resource folder it looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.4/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('MY_KEY_PLACED_HERE', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      forceTLS: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('form-submitted', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

==================================================================

then i create sender.blade.php inside resource

```
<form action="sender" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

=======================================================
i've set all credentials in .env file (here i have set proper key and secret)

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXX
PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXXXX
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=XXXX
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=AP2
```

=======================================================

```
and finally `web.php` looks like 


Route::get('/counter', function () {
    return view('counter');
});

Route::get('/sender', function () {
    return view('sender');
});

Route::post('/sender', function () {

    $text = request()->text;

    event(new FormSubmitted($text));
});
```

===========================================================
when i run localhost/counter in browser

i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined" this error in console

I expect the output of when i send localhost/sender  some input from text then this text data should be popup as a notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `header` `script` tag. You didn't end your jQuery `</script` tag properly. Change it to `</script>`.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you thank you very much for noticing my silly mistake... this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined" has been gone now , but when i send some input from sender page its show some error with black screen

Comment: That's another error, please create another question.